# mouseover event for menustripitem

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseover, menustrip

I have some menustrip Items in my menustrip.I want to set the color of the menustrip item when the mouse is on the menustripitem.Is it possible to have mouseover event for a menustripitem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own renderer and assign the MenuStrip.Renderer property.  Here's an example, it is going to need some work to look better:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
    }
    private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
        protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Item.Selected) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Bisque, e.Item.Bounds);
            }
            else base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use MouseEnter event of menustripitem.