# Change background color of Menustrip?

Tags: c#, menustrip

I'm using a `Menu Strip` and want to change background color when one of them selected.
for more explain,remember that i want change only main menu and no sub items.
thanks
I want to change background color of item1 and 2 and 3,when they're selected. 
for more explain:
I want to change `Main Menu Item` (and they are :Item1 & Item2 & Item3) and no sub items.

[image]

Comment: Define selected. Are we talking about mouse over or having their checked property set to checked ?

Comment: @coolmine : I want when select an Item (for example Item2) change background color from its default to blue.

Comment: @HansPassant: you mistake!my question isn't that you think

Comment: Hmm, sure it is.  Just override the color you care about in the color table.  If you want to change the selection color then override the MenuItemSelectedXxxx properties.

Comment: @HansPassant : I change picture of my question and more explain about it! now please answer me.tnx

Comment: Now it is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7415202/17034)

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks,it's not important for me that m answer is duplicate!!! but very important to give my answer from you! ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the background color when a menu item is clicked (but not for its child items) simply handle the `ItemClicked` event of your menustrip

```
private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickedItem.BackColor != Color.Blue)
        e.ClickedItem.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

**Note:** when you mouseover the items their color will be different while the mouse is over the item. For that you will require to create your own `Renderer` for your menustrip.